# Hadoop java mapper job executing on slave node, directory issue

Tags: java, caching, hadoop, mapreduce

As part of my Java mapper I have a command executes some standalone code on a local slave node.  When I run a code it executes fine, unless it is trying to access some local files in which case I get the error that it cannot locate those files.

Digging a little deeper it seems to be executing from the following directory:

> /data/hadoop/mapred/local/taskTracker/{user}/jobcache/job_201109261253_0023/attempt_201109261253_0023_m_000001_0/work

But I am intending to execute from a local directory where the relevant files are located:

> /home/users/{user}/input/jobname

Is there a way in java/hadoop to force the execution from the local directory, instead of the jobcache directory automatically created in hadoop?

Is there perhaps a better way to go about this?

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why are you accessing it? To run some shell script? To read something from local file?

Comment: I'm running a shell script from the java mapper code.  That script needs to access local files (that are relative to the execution directory).

Comment: When I ssh into the node and run the script manually it runs fine ...

Comment: Is the mapper able to call the script? In that case, you can give full path in the script.

Comment: Yeah, I've been able to call the script.  Unfortunately the executable is compiled and can't be edited so I can't put the full path in there...

Comment: If there are hardcoded paths in the executable, I don't think this is possible. But there must be a way to specify a root directory in the executable. For example, if it a java class, you can add the location to the classpath while calling the executable.

Comment: @Joris - Could you answer your own query with the discussion at the mapreduce-user@hadoop.apache.org group. This would be useful to everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround method I'm using right now that works consists of copying all the relevant files over to the jobcache working directory.  Then you can copy the results back to user directory if necessary.

Unfortunately this doesn't fully answer the question, but hopefully provides a useful workaround for others.

Cheers,

Joris